# Regarding passing variables to an argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments

I am working in python 2.7.8.

I'm currently learning about parameters and methods. What I'm trying to accomplish is have a user enter two different variables then pass them to an argument within different methods, sum() and difference().

My following code is something like this:

```
def computeSum(x, t):
    x = int(raw_input('Please enter an integer: '))
    t = int(raw_input('Please enter a second integer: '))
    x+t
return Sum

def computeDif(y, j):
    y = int(raw_input('Please enter an integer: '))
    j = int(raw_input('Please enter a second integer: '))
    y+j
return Dif

def main():
    raw_input('Would you like to find the sum of two numbers or the difference of two numbers?: ')
    answer = 'sum'
while True:
    computeSum()
else:
    computeDif()
```

For some reason my compiler (pyScriptor) isn't running and I cannot see any output nor error messages, its just blank. Can anyone possibly help me with any syntax/logic errors?

Comment: Are you calling `main` at the end?

Comment: Your `return` lines aren't indented and your `while` loop isn't either. Is this intentional, or did copying it over here screw it up?

Comment: You also need to assign output to the variables `Sum` and `Dif` to return them, e.g. `Sum = x + t`.

Comment: Or, get rid of those useless `Sum` and `Dif` entirely, and just change the last line of each function to `return x+t` and `return y+j`. (Although I'm not sure why you're adding two numbers to return the difference…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code

- Your indentation is way off
- `computeSum` and `computeDif` expect the two numbers as parameters, but then also ask for them from the terminal
- You return the variables `Sum` and `Dif`, but never assign values to them
- You call either `computeSum` or `computeDif`, but never do anything with the returned value
- You never call `main`. Do you know that you don't need a `main` function? You can just put the code in line after the function definitions

This is probably a little closer to what you had in mind

```
def computeSum(x, t):
    return x + t

def computeDif(y, j):
    return y - j

def main():
    while True:
        answer = raw_input('Would you like to find the "sum" of two numbers or the "dif"ference of two numbers? ')
        a = int(raw_input('Please enter an integer: '))
        b = int(raw_input('Please enter a second integer: '))

        if answer == 'sum':
            print(computeSum(a, b))
        elif answer == 'dif':
            print(computeDif(a, b))
        else:
            print('Please enter "sum" or "dif"')

main()
```

Comment: thank you! this made the problem a lot more clear to me. Now I just need to find a good compiler to start coding again!

Comment: JetBrains' *PyCharm* is excellent, and there is a [free version here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't need a `main()` function. Just put the code, unindented, by itself, and it will run when you run the program.

Comment: You _could_ do that, but it unnecessarily pollutes the global scope, so it's much neater to use a `main()`.